# Using filters within a cut command

Tags: bash, grep, cut

Hello for an assignment I have been given a file that is formatted as such

```
k2mff:x:32162:30:NJIT Amateur Radio Club:/afs/cad/u/k/2/k2mff:/usr/local/etc/klub/clubshell
senate:x:32164:30:The NJIT Student Senate:/afs/cad/u/s/e/senate:/usr/local/etc/klub/clubshell
ge:x:32184:30:Hongya Ge:/afs/cad/u/g/e/ge:/bin/tcsh
spasovic:x:32186:30:lazar spasovic fac/staff:/afs/cad/u/s/p/spasovic:/bin/csh
etc...
```

I am using a grep command to obtain the bold fields:

```
grep "csh" /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 3,5,6
```

My question is, since the `cut` command uses the delimiter, field six would return

```
/afs/cad/u/s/p/spasovic
```

Is there a way I can only retrieve, specifically for field six, the characters behind the last `/` within the `cut` command? Or do I have to filter the output to another command?

Comment: grep "csh" /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 3,5,6| sed 's#/.*/##g'  may work for you

Comment: Or better yet, `awk -F: '$7 ~ /\/csh$/ {print $3, $5,  gensub(".*/", "", "g", $6) }' /etc/passwd`. Or, unless you actually have users that have a home directory not equivalent to their user name - `awk -F: '$7 ~ /\/csh$/ {print $3, $5, $1}' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash's ability to split a line on a delimiter (`$IFS`) to get the different fields and the `${var##glob}` parameter expansion to remove portions of particular fields.

So you can have like:

```
# read each line and split it into named variables
while IFS=: read -r name pw uid gid gecos home shell; do
    # check the part after `/' in $shell 
    if [[ "${shell##*/}" == csh ]]; then
        # print the fields you want
        echo "$uid" "$gecos" "${home##*/}"
    fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

You can add other if/then statements to this loop to print other fields based on other conditions, etc.